# Reusing class best practice

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, uiview

My UIView (**ClassA**) has a button that when pressed shows another UIView (**ColorClass**) with 3 buttons that allows a user to select a color.  The color that is selected is passed back to **ClassA** so that it can be worked with. It is also passed to a *Storage* (a singleton) class for saving the selected color.

This works great, but now, I need a second unrelated class **ClassB**, to have same functionality. But when I call the same method I normally call in **ClassA** from inside **ClassB**, **ClassA** is the one that is updated.

How can I make **ColorClass** more agnostic to the calling class? I am still learning so if someone could help point me in the right direction that would be great.

**ClassA**

```
- (void) showColorPicker{
    CGRect colorPickerFrame = CGRectMake(150, 100, 237, 215);
colorPicker= [[ColorClass alloc] initWithFrame:colorPickerFrame];
    colorPicker.vc = self;
    [self.view insertSubview:colorPicker aboveSubview:self.view];
}

- (void) setTheButtonColor : (int) c {

    Sufficient to say this just changes the buttons background color selected from a list of colors 
}
```

**ColorClass**

When a selected color is pressed, I call this method that messages ClassA with the color.

```
- (void) buttonPressed : (id) sender {
        [self.vc setButtonColor:[sender tag]];
    [myStorage setButtonColor:[sender tag]];
}
```

[image: Layout]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `delegation` - like when you supply the data for a `UITableView` it doesn't know exactly what your class is, just that it implements a specified `@protocol`.

Define your own protocol which describes the callback offered (this goes in ColorClass.h):

```
@protocol ColorClassDelegate < NSObject >

- (void)colorPicker:(ColorClass *)colorPicker didPickColor:(UIColor *)color;

@end
```

Then in your `ColorClass` (again, the .h file) you have a property for the delegate:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id < ColorClassDelegate > delegate;
```

When the colour has been chosen (button pressed):

```
- (void) buttonPressed : (id) sender {
    // delegate
    [self.delegate colorPicker:self didPickColor:   ## get the colour here ##   ];

    // persistent store
    [myStorage setButtonColor:[sender tag]];
}
```

And any class that uses the colour picker implements the `ColorClassDelegate` protocol

```
#import "ColorClass.h"

@interface ClassA < ColorClassDelegate >
```

And sets itself as the colour pickers delegate. Then it implements:

```
- (void)colorPicker:(ColorClass *)colorPicker didPickColor:(UIColor *)color
{

    // do something with the colour

}
```

Your original code was passing the button tag to represent the colour. You could do that instead of passing the colour in the delegate method.

Comment: Would I still need to @class the ViewControllor using your method? That is the only way I know how to message between classes. I very much appreciate your help. Would it be to much to ask if you could create a boilerplate in xcode? I understand what is happening I just don't understand the overall implementation.

Comment: Thank you so much! When you told me about delagates I Googled it and found this great article! You just made my day! http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that might be a bit less involved than a delegate but loosely coupled is using **NSNotification**.

And blast a notification when the color is selected.

If you would like some example code I can provide, but **NSNotification** is pretty strait forward.